# angular-cli:why when new module install by npm an old module be removed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

i have ng-sidebar module for my app but when i install new module like ng2-d&d:

```
npm install ng2-dnd --save
```

old module remove from app-module and following error occurres :

> Cannot find module ng-sidebar.

i tried to find ng-sidebar in node module but i I didn't find it.i install ng-sidebar.

```
npm install ng-sidebar --save
```

but last module that i install missed from `node-module`.

Comment: Was it removed from you `package.json` as well?

Comment: @AluanHaddad haddad no there is ng-sidebar in package.json after install new module

Comment: May be that included in `app.module.ts` file you need to remove it from there also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i delete `package-lock.json` and then i go to root directory  i write `npm update` in command and now it's working